# Why do words and distances of gensim Word2Vec and "Nearest points in the original space" of Embedding Projector of TensorFlow are different?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gensim, word2vec

I'm using gensim Word2Vec to create word vectors and evaluate similarities through the `most_similar` method, and gensim `word2vec2tensor` script output to visualize the word vectors in the Embedding Projector of TensorFlow.

Considering a given word, ex: economy, the computed cosine distances (1 - cosine similarity) of its most similar words using the `most_similar` similarities are different from the ones displayed at "Nearest points in the original space (distance cosine)" of Embedding Projector, and I also get different similar words. What am I missing? Or what is wrong with the "Nearest points in the original space (distance cosine)" of Embedding Projector? I know there are the dimension reduction procedures that would affect the results, but it is stated "Nearest points in the ORIGINAL SPACE", so I don't get it.

Here follows 2 images as an example of the word 'economia':
[Top 8 similar words to 'economia' using `most_similar`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UiXn.png)
and
[Top 8 nearest words displayed by 'Nearest points in the original space' using the gensim word vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6ucz.png).

Comment: If using exact same set-of-word-vectors in both tools, then ranked list of words from `most_similar()` (by cosine-sims closest to 1.0), & ranked list of words from "nearest points in the original space" (smallest cosine-distances) should be identical. If they are not, you may be making some other error. You should add more details to your Q about the exact steps you've followed, & code run, to analyze the same vecs in both tools – & show differing outputs/values observed for specific words. (Also, do you see similar diffs using some public set of wordvecs, in a way others could reproduce?)

Comment: I agree, I just can't figure out what I'm missing. I'll add more details soon (I just added 2 pictures as an example for the word 'economia'), what I can tell now is that I'm training a skip-gram model using gensim and saving the word vectors using `save_word2vec_format`. Then I use the `word2vec2tensor` script to convert the vectors from word2vec format into tensor, and follow the steps here https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/word2vec2tensor.html to visualize it. I didn't test using public sets, but good point, I'll do it! Thanks @gojomo ( :

Comment: You might also be able to make a self-contained reproduction using some small public corpus (eg `text8` from compression benchmarks, used in some Gensim demo notebooks) or small public word-vector set (which you can truncate on `.load_word2vec_format()` using the `limit` parameter to something minimal, like a few tens-of-thousands of words instead of hundreds-of-thousands/milllions).